# npm modules update and git branches

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I would like to know how to manage dependencies updates between branches.

Example:

- Working on branch A with a module in v3
- Updating the module via npm on branch B
- Working on branch A again

Since modules in node_modules are the same between branches, the module is still in v4 when back on branch A.
This generates an error because a function doesn't exist in v4 anymore.

Is there a way to manage this without having to re-install the correct version each time we switch branches ?

Comment: No, there isn't; the *content* of `node_modules` is generally not under version control, just the dependency definitions in `package.json`.

Comment: You wouldn’t want to commit node modules. It be a big pain

Comment: I don't want to commit node modules. Actually, I was hoping someone would know a best practice in this case.

Comment: Probably you can use `post-checkout` [git hook](https://schacon.github.io/git/githooks.html#_post_checkout) to automate switching module versions on branch change.

Or you could just have 2 separate folders(working directories) with the respective branches checked out.